# Excel - Show List of names when value in cell is

Tags: excel

i need to show a list of names when in cell A1 value is like **Type 1**

I have a table with the headlines **machine types** | **names** | **e-Mail address**

So in cell A1 i can choose with a dropdown five different types. In cell B1 to B10 i want now that it shows all the names from the table which have **Type 1**.

So far i could not find a solution which could solve my problem.

I already tried the **IF-Function** and the **VLOOKUP-Function**, but both of them don´t really work.

**EDIT**

I tried this:

=IF(A1="Type 1";VLOOKUP(A1;C1:D10;1;WRONG);"AAA")

And

=VLOOKUP("Type 1";C1:D10;1;WRONG)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but have you tried using a pivot table, it has a built in sorting function.

Comment: Unfortunately a pivot table doesn´t help me with that

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: no longer in the office .. sorry .. do you think this problem could be solved with an vba code?